# What are the correct authentication settings for an on-premise ADFS flow?

Tags: authentication, iis, owin, adfs

I've been reading Vittorio Bertocci's blog to try to get up to speed on using ADFS to manage authentication and claims in either an MVC app or WebApi service. It looks like it's getting to be very approachable.

I am now trying to build out a POC using ADFS to do common claims resolution for internal sites/services in our enterprise. Our users would be on the internal network along with our endpoints. Right now we use Windows Integrated auth by default and each site does the work of looking up a user’s name, email, and other AD details and inspecting the claims principal for roles via IsInRole. The claims we get with integrated auth includes just a SamIdentifier and a bunch of group SIDs. I’d like ADFS to do that work for us but still give our users a challenge-free experience. Long term, we will likely add support for non-domain-joined devices on some sites/services, so that is another motivation to explore ADFS.

So I've set up a simple sample app in VS2013 using Organizational Accounts (On Premise) that will dump out a current user's claims, configured the metadata endpoint and audience uri, communicated that info along with the claims I'd like mapped to my ADFS admin (2012, btw), and deployed my site to a development server. So my host is still IIS, though I hope to use Owin middleware to set up authentication rather than web.config (WIF-style).

Given that IIS is my host, how do I configure authentication for my site: anonymous? And my web.config should specify "None" for the authentication mode and deny="?" for authorization, correct?

The other question I have that Vittorio didn't get into in his post about on-premise adfs was the nature of the bearer token and whether or not we need to explicitly configure the middleware to use cookies. My startup config looks like this right now:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
            new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"] }
            });
    }
```

It looks like this middleware is expecting JWT tokens (given that there is a JwtSecurityTokenHandler on the class). Is there any configuration we need to do on the ADFS side to issue JWT tokens? My understanding is that I'll receive a SAML token by default.

And should we expect to use the CookieAuthentication middleware to manage the token or will the browser just keep including it for the life of the session?

Thanks, all!

UPDATE:
So based on Vittorio's help below and some further research, I now have a simple website with just one page protected with an [Authorize] attribute. My startup class's ConfigureAuth method now looks like this:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
            new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"] }
            });
    }
```

We've added my website as a relying party trust in ADFS and created a half dozen claims rules. Everything seems correct so far, but I'm still struggling. I hit the protected "claims" page and get a 401 response with a WWW-Authenticate:Bearer header. So far, so good.

But that's it. How does the browser know where to get authenticated and receive a token? If I was proving out the separate client scenario, my client would be configured with the location of the token authority, but in this simple website scenario, I'm clearly missing something.

UPDATE 2:
I wonder if the implementation for on-premise ADFS just isn't ready yet? Or perhaps the documentation just isn't there yet - or both...

I pulled out all the Owin packages and reverted to using the WSFederationAuthenticationModule and SessionAuthenticationModule, along with all the web.config settings in system.identityModel and system-identityModel.services that have been around a while. Basically, I made the solution look like the one you get from VS2013 when you selected Organizational Accounts --> On Premise. Everything works beautifully and I have all my configured claims coming from ADFS. I see the initial 302 redirect to ADFS, the challenge-response, and ultimately have a SAML token serialized into a secure session cookie. On the website, I echo back the claims like so:

```
var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
ViewBag.Claims = user.Claims;
return View();
```

This is why I suspect the middleware is incomplete: when you use that new template in VS2013, the wizard goes to the federation metadata endpoint you specify and builds out all the web.config settings by reading that xml and, in addition, sets some intelligent defaults. That's sort of what I expected to happen in the Owin middleware - it should have everything it needs to know since I pass in the same metadata endpoint. I was hoping that "magic" would replace using the FAM/SAM modules and all the accompanying config.

Comment: Did you ever try getting the Bearer token from the cookie on the client side (using javascript) and putting it in the Request Authorization Header?  (`Authorization: Bearer asdfghjkl`).  My impression is that you would need to do this to access an API from a javascript client app.

Comment: Not using the Owin middleware. The problem I continue to have is that the website (my application) does not respond to an unauthorized request with a 302 redirect to the ADFS endpoint configured in the startup.cs code. It simply returns a 401. Without that redirect, all clients must know to first go to the ADFS server to get a token.

Comment: @Stuart, my statement  _var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;_ returns null. So I am not able to read the claims. What I need to change for reading claims? Is there configuration wise change?

Answer (score 7):

1) If you are configuring a web UX app, that is something meant to be consumed through browser redirects, you want to use http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/29/use-the-owin-security-components-in-asp-net-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs/. You'll see that the cookie middleware does come into play in that case.

2) If you are configuring a web API, as in something that is consumed by a rich client or another server, or in general anything that is not a browser roundtripping, see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/. In that case you do not need cookies, given that there is no session -every single call must carry the token.

HTH
V.

Comment: Thanks. I'm starting with scenario 1, so I've configured the cookie middleware as well.

Comment: Option 1 is cookies?  Is there a risk of CSRF?  Cookies would be automatically included with each request...  Option 2 is tokens?  If you use a JS front end, you would need to persist the bearer token in HTML5 sessionStorage and then include it with each request?

Answer (score -1):

As Vittorio said you need to differentiate if you create a web page with web api or web api only. Follow his blog posts they are great!!

If you host a webapi only project in an IIS you need to set the authentication to "forms authentication". 
This works also if your web api is covered behind a web application proxy. make sure that you configure your endpoint (published web application) not to preauthenticate. the value for "preauthenticate" should be "pass through".

bg Andrej